# DLLImport a variable MFC dll

Tags: c#, mfc, pinvoke

So I created the following test project:

```
[DllImportAttribute("TestMFCDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern int test(int number);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = test(5);
}
```

Which works fine for my MFC dll that has the function test defined, however what I actually have is many MFC dlls that all share a common entry function and run differently based on my inputs.  So basically I have tons of dlls that I cannot know at compile time what the name is, I just know that they have a function similar to how this program is setup, is there a way to import a dll based on run-time knowledge?  Simply doing this returns an error:

```
static string myDLLName = "TestMFCDLL.dll";
[DllImportAttribute(myDLLName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically P/Invoking a DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202744/dynamically-p-invoking-a-dll)

Comment: To all those voting to close, I think the answer given for this question is much better than that of the duplicate, so at least migrate it over if you are going to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to dynamically load a DLL and use the functions in the DLL, then you'll need to do a little bit more. First you need to load the DLL dynamically. You can use LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary for that.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
```

Second you need to get the address of the function in the DLL and call it.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string functionName);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate int Test(int number);
```

Putting that all together:

```
IntPtr pLib = LoadLibrary(@"PathToYourDll.DLL");
IntPtr pAddress = GetProcAddress(pLib, "test");
Test test = (Test)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddress, typeof(Test));
int iRresult = test(0);
bool bResult = FreeLibrary(pLib);
```

Comment: Perfect, I actually got it working right as you answered, but I didn't include the FreeLibrary which is probably important.  Thanks for the solution!

Comment: If you do not call FreeLibrary, then the library will be kept in memory. So if you have a loop where you walk over a bunch of DLLs, load them, call test and do not call FreeLibrary, then all the DLLs will be kept in memory and you might run out of memory. If your program only needs to load one DLL at startup and free it when terminating, you could also omit FreeLibrary. Of course I'ld prefer to do a proper cleanup.