# windows service Can't call C++ Native Methods [DllImpor("myDLL")]

Tags: c#, c++, windows-services, pinvoke, dllimport

I tried to use this way: 
[DLLImport a variable MFC dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628211/dllimport-a-variable-mfc-dll)
It works.

The problem is the `C++ dll "myDLL"` needs another **DLL "XDLL"**,
I found that 
the service current fodler when services started is the system32, not where the assemble are !!!
In this case, if I put `"XDLL"` in *system32* it would work...

What I need is away to run it without copying anything to *System32* or anyway else

Is it `C#` windows service issue ? or `C++` ? what should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Just put it in the same folder as your service exe. Then Google "SxS DLL"

Comment: didn't work because for the service current fodler when services started is the system32 its not where the assemble are !

Comment: so #ta.speot.is , if you can't answer plz remove your (-1 ) for this question

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#standard_search_order_for_desktop_applications *1. The directory from which the application loaded.*

Comment: Thanks I'll try to understand that

Answer (score 2):

If DLLs are specified by name only, that is without a complete path, then the [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) comes into play.

There are lots of ifs and buts with this, but the bottom line is that if you put all the DLLs that your executable needs in the same directory as the executable, then the loader will be able to find the DLLs. That is the best practice because it requires no configuration, and you can be certain of which version of the DLL is to be loaded.