# Dynamically invoke unmanaged code from C#

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

In general I need to be able to invoke any unmanaged function from any DLL which I don't know at the compile time.

All the articles I seen (like this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jonathanswift/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-net-c/) suggest using delegates but I don't know at the compile time which function I gonna invoke and even which and how many parameters it requires.

Basically I have a user input like: call "Kernel32.dll" function "DeleteFile" arguments ["C:\testfile.txt"].

Could you please advice at least how to google it? The word "dynamically" doesn't help..

The task itself is a bit crazy just because actually it's a university project. Not sure it can be useful in real life..

```
var dll = "kernel32.dll";
var fun = "DeleteFile";
var args = new object[] { "C:\\dev\\test.txt" };

IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(dll);

IntPtr pFun = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, fun);

// How can I call it in a different way, without having a delegate?
Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pFun, typeof(?????));
```

Comment: Unless you know the arguments and types of a native method, there is no way you can do this dynamically. Do you expect your users to supply and know this?

Comment: Yeah, the users are actually the programmers since I create a compiler.. The thing is the users can do any WinAPI call outside of my C# runtime

Comment: So they should be able to write something like CallExternal("kernel32.dll", "DeleteFile", "C:\\file.txt")

Comment: Given you know the callsite argument types, you can still generate a delegate for it. Edit: You would still have to guess the return type, but usually `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically P/Invoking a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202744/dynamically-p-invoking-a-dll)

Comment: that duplicate has a link to an article which has exactly your scenario

Comment: @KeithNicholas Holding out on closing as the question seems a bit more 'dynamic'.

Comment: This article is really very close but it's code doesn't work.. It says that Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer can't work with Func or Action. Error message is "The specified Type must not be a generic type definition".

Comment: But in the example they use Action<String>.. weird

Comment: So this is really the duplicate but the question isn't solved completely there. I can even push the users to provide the list of argument types but I can't create the "non-generic" delegate in runtime..

Comment: then go with the code gen approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also agree with idea of Roslyn, but when I see **"Dynamic"** and **"P/Invoke"**, *good old* `System.Reflection.Emit` comes to mind:

```
var asmName = new AssemblyName("Win32");
var asmBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
var modBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Win32", emitSymbolInfo: false);
var typeBuilder = modBuilder.DefineType("Win32.User32", TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public);

// Optional: Use if you need to set properties on DllImportAttribute
var dllImportCtor = typeof(DllImportAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
var dllImportBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(dllImportCtor, new object[] { "user32.dll" });

var pinvokeBuilder = typeBuilder.DefinePInvokeMethod(
    name:              "ShowMessageBox",
    dllName:           "user32.dll",
    entryName:         "MessageBoxW",
    attributes:        MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public,
    callingConvention: CallingConventions.Standard,
    returnType:        typeof(int),  // typeof(void) if there is no return value.
    // TODO: Construct this array from user input somehow:
    parameterTypes:    new Type[] { typeof(IntPtr), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(uint) },
    nativeCallConv:    CallingConvention.Winapi,
    nativeCharSet:     CharSet.Unicode);

pinvokeBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(dllImportBuilder);

Type user32Type = typeBuilder.CreateType();

const uint MB_YESNOCANCEL = 3;

user32Type
    .GetMethod("ShowMessageBox", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    // TODO: User input goes here:
    .Invoke(null, new object[] { IntPtr.Zero, "Message Text", "Message Caption", MB_YESNOCANCEL });
```

Not pretty, I know. Just my $0.02.

WARNING: If this code is going to be called multiple times in a long running application, consider creating a new `AppDoman` each time, and disposing it when call is done; because this is the only way to unload generated dynamic assembly.

Comment: Thank you so much George! This is exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what the end goal is, but I would take a slightly different approach.   In .NET compilers are a service you can use, so you can dynamically generate an assembly and then load it and use it.  So your program essentially is a "generator" you translate the input into code, compile it, load it, run it.   You can use roslyn for this.

Comment: The end goal is just to invoke unmanaged DLL without describing a delegate just because I don't know the function signature.

Comment: I agree with this approach. The way you initially explained it would be a big security flaw on many levels. Nothing inside of .Net is going to let you do something that could cause a stack overflow. That would open the door to stack smashing.